# Передача видео частями в браузер

Tags: c#, http, .net-7

Решил для практики написать небольшой сервер, который будет отдавать частями видео в браузер. Решил писать на TCPListener. Почему-то когда я отдаю видео в браузер оно до конца не грузится и появляются ошибки во вкладке браузера "Сеть"(скрин ниже). Пожалуйста, подскажите, что исправить в коде. Код, который обрабатывает всё основное(считывает файл и отправляет в браузер) также ниже.

```
using System.Text;

namespace Server
{
    public class StaticVidepHandler : IHandler
    {
        private readonly string _path;

        public StaticVidepHandler(string path)
        {
            _path= path;
        }

        public async Task Handle(Stream networkStream)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(networkStream))
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(networkStream))
            {
                var headersDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                var httpRequestString = reader.ReadLine();

                for (string line = null; line != string.Empty; line = reader.ReadLine()) 
                {

                    if(line == null) continue;

                    headersDictionary.Add(line.Split(" ")[0], line.Split(" ")[1]);
                }
                
                var requestParsed = RequestParser.Parse(httpRequestString);

                var filePath = Path.Combine(_path, requestParsed.Path);

                if (!File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    //TODO: Send 404 error
                }
                else
                {
                    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
                    long size = (long)file.Length;

                    byte[] chunk = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 4]; // чанк 4MB
                    long startPosition = 0;
                    int index = 0;

                    if (headersDictionary.Keys.Contains("Range:"))
                    {
                        int.TryParse(headersDictionary["Range:"].Split(new char[] { '=', '-' })[1], out int range);

                        startPosition = range;
                    }

                    if ((size - startPosition) < chunk.Length)
                    {
                        chunk = new byte[size - startPosition];
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        using(var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
                        {
                            fileStream.Position = startPosition;

                            var chunkSize = fileStream.Read(chunk, index, chunk.Length);

                            Console.WriteLine(chunk.Length);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(ex); 
                    }

                    byte[] httpHeadersBytes = httpHeadersBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                        "HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content\r\n" +
                        $"Content-Length: {file.Length}\r\n" +
                        "Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n" +
                        $"Content-Range: bytes {startPosition} - {file.Length - 1} / {file.Length}\r\n" +
                        $"Content-Type: video/webm\r\n\r\n");

                    byte[] httpResponseBytes = httpHeadersBytes.Concat(chunk).ToArray();

                    writer.BaseStream.Write(httpResponseBytes, 0, httpResponseBytes.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Ошибка в браузере]

Comment: Во-первых, Content-Length должен содержать размер переданной части, а не размер файла целиком. Во-вторых, в Content-Range не допускаются пробелы

Comment: В третьих, не рекомендую писать веб-серверы с нуля кроме как в образовательных целях, уже есть куча серверов, которые работают лучше и быстрее, чем то, что сможете сделать вы

Comment: В-четвёртых, здесь уже есть ряд примеров серверов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A373567+tcplistener

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо, всё заработало. Сервер писал в образовательных целях